# Parenthesis Matching with Boolean Expression

Tags: c

```
//JOSE DENNIS CHUA 

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define bool int

/* structure of a stack node */
struct sNode
{
   char data;
   struct sNode *next;
};

/* Function to push an item to stack*/
void push(struct sNode** top_ref, int new_data);

/* Function to pop an item from stack*/
int pop(struct sNode** top_ref);

/* Returns 1 if character1 and character2 are matching left
   and right Parenthesis */
bool isMatchingPair(char character1, char character2)
{
   if(character1 == '(' && character2 == ')')
     return 1;
   else
     return 0;
}

/*Return 1 if expression has balanced Parenthesis */
bool areParenthesisBalanced(char exp[])
{
   int i = 0;

   /* Declare an empty character stack */
   struct sNode *stack = NULL;

   /* Traverse the given expression to check matching parenthesis */
   while(exp[i])
   {
      /*If the exp[i] is a starting parenthesis then push it*/
      if(exp[i] == '(')
        push(&stack, exp[i]);

      /* If exp[i] is a ending parenthesis then pop from stack and 
          check if the popped parenthesis is a matching pair*/
      if(exp[i] == ')')
      {

          /*If we see an ending parenthesis without a pair then return false*/
         if(stack == NULL)
           return 0; 

         /* Pop the top element from stack, if it is not a pair 
            parenthesis of character then there is a mismatch.
            This happens for expressions like {(}) */
         else if ( !isMatchingPair(pop(&stack), exp[i]) )
           return 0;
      }
      i++;
   }

   /* If there is something left in expression then there is a starting
      parenthesis without a closing parenthesis */
   if(stack == NULL)
     return 1; /*balanced*/
   else
     return 0;  /*not balanced*/
} 

/* UTILITY FUNCTIONS */
/

*driver program to test above functions*/
int main()
{
  char exp[100];

printf("Enter String: ");
  gets(exp);
  if(areParenthesisBalanced(exp))
    printf("\n Balanced ");
  else
    printf("\n Not Balanced ");  \
  getchar();
}    

/* Function to push an item to stack*/
void push(struct sNode** top_ref, int new_data)
{
  /* allocate node */
  struct sNode* new_node =
            (struct sNode*) malloc(sizeof(struct sNode));

  if(new_node == NULL)
  {
     printf("Stack overflow \n");
     getchar();
     exit(0);
  }           

  /* put in the data  */
  new_node->data  = new_data;

  /* link the old list off the new node */
  new_node->next = (*top_ref);  

  /* move the head to point to the new node */
  (*top_ref)    = new_node;
}

/* Function to pop an item from stack*/
int pop(struct sNode** top_ref)
{
  char res;
  struct sNode *top;

  /*If stack is empty then error */
  if(*top_ref == NULL)
  {
     printf("Stack overflow \n");
     getchar();
     exit(0);
  }
  else
  {
     top = *top_ref;
     res = top->data;
     *top_ref = top->next;
     free(top);
     return res;
  }
}
```

This is my Code, and I dont have idea where to put the code for separating the boolean expression for the parenthesis.. can anyone give me code for this..

### Problem Definition.

In computer science, a Boolean expression is an expression in a programming language that produces a Boolean value when evaluated, i.e. one of true or false. A Boolean expression may be composed of a combination of the Boolean constants true or false, Boolean-typed variables, Boolean-valued operators, and Boolean-valued functions [wiki]. Examples of Boolean expression are the following:

```
x<=1
((x>0) && (x<10))
(!x || !y)
```

With the use of parenthesis in grouping Boolean expressions within another Boolean expression, your task is to develop a module that will identify if a given Boolean expression is correct in terms of the pairing of parenthesis present in the expression.

### Example Program Output.

```
Input String (Boolean Expression): xValue<=1

Identification Result: Parenthesis pairs complete

Input String (Boolean Expression): ((teen>9) && (teen<20))

Identification Result: Parenthesis pairs complete

Input String (Boolean Expression): (!myAge) || !yourAge)

Identification Result: Parenthesis pairs incomplete

Input String (Boolean Expression): (total<=0( || )total>=10)

Identification Result: Parenthesis pairs incomplete
```

### Mandatory Requirement.

Apply the Stack ADT concept in solving the given problem. You are free to choose either array or linkedlist implementation provided that the only limit of the program during execution is the memory space.

Comment: What have you tried?  What didn't work?  What did it do, and what did you expect?

Comment: "Input String (Boolean Expression): (total<=0( || )total>=10)"

in this case, the Identification result is complete..
it should be incomplete..

Comment: Your task, should you choose to accept it, is to verify that each open parenthesis '(' has a matching closing parenthesis, ')'.

Comment: Please edit your question with your code.

Comment: * Returns 1 if character1 and character2 are matching left
   and right Parenthesis */
bool isMatchingPair(char character1, char character2)
{
   if(character1 == '(' && character2 == ')')
     return 1;
   else if(character1 == '{' && character2 == '}')
     return 1;
   else if(character1 == '[' && character2 == ']')
     return 1;
   else
     return 0;
}

Comment: @TonyD "Input String (Boolean Expression): (total<=0( || )total>=10)" in this case, the Identification result is complete.. it should be incomplete..

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I dont have any idea how to get the boolean expression out of the parenthesis

Comment: I will make a new one..

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: I just made a new post for my problem.. please help me for this thing.

Comment: This smells a lot like homework, but it does not follow the [guidelines for asking homework questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/).

Comment: @user3072691: Please see my answer.  If you need more details, *talk with your instructor*, as that's what they get paid for.

Comment: @RemyLebeau i'm a newbie sir.. :)

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: ok sir.. tnx for the help :)

Comment: If you want my help, you'll have to think for yourself, as I don't give away free code.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: I just edited my post... See the codes I made, if u have any idea how to get the boolean expression if i will input a string..

Comment: I don't see how a newbie can be given an assignment like this.  Use `std::string::substr()` to extract the text between parenthesis.  Use `std::string::find` to find the parenthesis.  I recommend taking a less advanced course.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: I think stl string is only for c++???

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, you issue is how to parse the Boolean expression out of the parenthesis.

From your post assume the following classes of "tokens":

- Parenthesis
- Operators
- Identifiers

**Operators**
Operators are one or more symbol characters associated with identifiers.  The result of evaluating the symbols yields a Boolean result.

Some *Boolean* operators from the C and C++ languages:

```
==, !=, <, <=, >, >=,  
&&, ||
```

**Identifiers**
From your post, identifiers can be numbers or "variable names".
Examples:  `49, myVar, ketchup96`

**Parenthesis**
The foundation of your assignment is identifying and matching the parenthesis pairs, open and close.  The other part is identifying valid Boolean expressions.

**The parsing tree**
A common data structure for parsing is a binary tree.  A parent node is an operator and its two children are the identifiers.  The parenthesis determine how the parent and children are related, which is the exercise  of your assignment.

Using pen/pencil and paper, write a simple Boolean expression, such as: `4 < 5`.
Read the identifier: 4, create node and put into tree.
Read the operator and create node.  Operator becomes parent, the identifier becomes the left child:

```
   <
 /
4
```

Read in next identifier, create node, add as right child of operator:

```
  <
 / \
4   5
```

Write down the steps.
Take another expression follow the same steps.

Now add in a 2nd expression and parenthesis.
*How would you change your algorithm (steps) to handle parenthesis and another expression?*

Keep refining your algorithm.
Finally, code your algorithm.
Test your code.

**ADT**
Search the web for "ADT tutorial" and also **talk with your instructor** about the ADT.

**Parsing strings**
Search the web and StackOverflow for "C++ parse input tokens".

Answer (score 0):

You are making the problem harder than it needs to be.

```
x<=1
((x>0) && (x<10))
(!x || !y)
```

These expressions only allow parenthesis, not brackets or braces.  So, there's no need to keep a stack recording which of parenthesis, brackets and braces has been encountered when... just keep a number recording the current depth of nesting.

I recommend that you use recursion to validate your input.  Specifically... scan from left to right considering whether the expression is legal so far, and if you reach "(" at a place where it's legal then recursively call your validation function passing the address of the next character... it should return when it's consumed the matching ")" and let you continue validating the rest of the expression on the basis that the "()" yielded a boolean value.